# Why does "position: relative" only work in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a table, which should be centered both horizontally and vertically. The horizontal centration works fine (using "margin: 0 auto"), but the vertical centration (using "position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)") only works in Google Chrome, in Firefox, Edge & MS Explorer it does not work. 
I found out that "transform" works like it is supposed to, but "position: relative" does not work in all browsers.

```html
<table border="1" id="content">
    <tr>
        <td><video id="video" controls></video></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
#content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15pt;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: -ms-translateY(-50%);
            -moz-transform: -moz-translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: -o-translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);    
            z-index: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that position relative doesn't allow you to use the `top`, `right`, etc. positioning. So it's only transforming your Y.

Change it to `position: absolute;` instead.

```css
#content {
    /* Center #content */
    margin: 0 auto;

    /* Align the text */
    text-align: center;

    /* Setting the font */
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15pt;

    /* Setting the position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;

    /* Transforming #content */
    -webkit-transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: -o-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="content">
    <tr>
        <td><video id="video" controls></video></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So simple. That could have come to my mind...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:100%;
}
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
```

If you want to use flex you can do it that way , thats all...

Answer (score -1):

Look at this;

https://jsfiddle.net/uniak/z9vmnde6/

```css
#content {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content td {}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="content">
  <tr>
    <td><video id="video" controls></video></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```